# IIS Redirect only for site Index

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I'm using IIS8 and trying to redirect a site homepage to another site based on the following conditions:

```
https://mysite.co.uk
http://mysite.co.uk
https://mysite.co.uk/
http://mysite.co.uk/
```

Should all redirect to: https://site2.co.uk/

Whereas any resource requests should not redirect, so none of the below:

```
https://mysite.co.uk/abc/def
http://mysite.co.uk/abc/def
https://mysite.co.uk/abc/def
http://mysite.co.uk/abc/def
```

I have tried many variations, but nothing I have tried so far has worked, this is my latest:

```
<rule name="Redirect Home Only" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.*)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://site2.co.uk" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Now I'm pretty sure that this should be trivial, so I would very much appreciate someone putting me out of my misery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect only an index url use following condition

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/$" />
```

For URL http://mysite.co.uk/abc/def IIS returns following server variables

```
REQUEST_URI = /abc/def
PATH_INFO   = /abc/def
```

For URL http://mysite.co.uk/ following

```
REQUEST_URI = /
PATH_INFO   = /
```

So alternatively you could use

```
<add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/$" />
```

See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/url-parts-available-to-url-rewrite-rules) for more details.